# RabbitMQ message cannot verify if it was sent

Tags: php, rabbitmq

The aim of my current task is to send data via RabbitMQ, a server was setup, and the code looks like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$host = "ip.address";
$port = 5672;
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$exchangeName = "@frontend-api/log";
$queueName = "log";

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection($host, $port, $username, $password);
$channel = $connection->channel();

// create the exchange if one doesn't exist
$channel->exchange_declare(
    $exchangeName,  # exchange name
    'direct',       # type
    false,          # passive
    true,           # durable
    false           # auto_delete
);

$channel->queue_declare($queueName, false, true, false, false);
$channel->queue_bind($queueName, $exchangeName, "log");

$message = new AMQPMessage('Hello World!');
$channel->basic_publish($message, $exchangeName);

echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
```

When I run the script, the echo message shows up, and when I login to RabbitMQ, I can see the queue, as well as the exchange.

However, I do not know if the message indeed went and my snippet is correct. And also, when I visit the queues page, I see that state of the queue says "idle". When does it change to "running"?

How do I verify if the message is being went?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue state is not the best way to check things in your context.

Based on your example, I'm assuming that there is no consumer on the queue for the moment, so if your code worked, you'd see the Messages - Ready count increase in the UI.

From the code you shared, your message will not reach the queue though, reason is that you have created a [direct exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-direct) with a "log" binding to your log queue.

So when you publish the message, it should have a routing key "log" for it to follow the binding and reach the queue.

From what I could find quickly, you should have

`$channel->basic_publish($message, $exchangeName, 'log');`

for it to work as you expect.